# Is it correct to use a regular variable (let, const) in React component?

Tags: reactjs

I work with React and when I need to create some variable I use for example or:

```
const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
```

or:

```
const canvas = useRef(null);
```

Are there any situations when I can use instead useState or useRef just regular variable

```
let a
```

and make regular assignment? I came across a code in which ordinary variables and ordinary assignments are applied, but it seems to me that this is not correct. Сan I replace let a = useRef(null) with let a = null

Answer (score 1):

- useState is when you want to re-render the whole component if the state changes
- useRef is when you want to persist a variable during renders

Other than that, you are free to use `let` or `const`

Like when you want to do some logic/calculation and reassign the variable itself.

Comment: That is, a regular variable and ref are interchangeable for a mutable variable. Right?

Comment: ref is used when you don't want a variable to lose its value during renders, you are free to set it to whatever value you'd like to.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `let` yes, but not for your above examples. You shouldn't use it for `useState` and `useEffect` etc..

Example of let:

```
const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
const [otherVar, setOtherVar] = useState(false);
let someVar = 12;
if (otherVar && show) someVar = 20;

return (<Component someProp={someVar} ... />)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a let here, but it's a convention to use const for functions, which is what your examples amount to.

Answer (score 0):

For `let` it's OK, but usually used when re-render is not wanted.

`const` is being used much more, and it should be. Because we don't want functionality of component to be overwritten by clumsy assignings.